# Thumbnail image is not fitting the entire column when resizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have included a `sidebar` in one column and `3 thumbnails` in another 3 columns in a `row`. The `thumbnail` image is fitting the entire `columns` at first but when I resize the `thumbnail images` are getting smaller keeping the `column` in full width (as for usual `bootstrap` responsive works). I need to stretch my `images` as that of the `column` they are filled in.

Here's my **HTML**:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid side-navigation-bar">
    <div class="row">
        <!--==========================================-->
        <!--Side navigation bar-->
        <!--==========================================-->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3-thumbnail">
            <div class="nav-side-menu" >
                <div class="brand"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"> myVitals.com</i></div>
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

                <div class="menu-list" >

                    <ul  id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out" >
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Home
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-book fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; My Appointments
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-s15 fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Facilities
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Services</a>
                        </li>  

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-stethoscope fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Doctors</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-medkit fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Medications
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-medkit fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Medications
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--==========================================-->
        <!--End of Side navigation bar-->
        <!--==========================================-->


        <!--==========================================-->
        <!--Cards-->
        <!--==========================================-->
        <div id="column" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3-thumbnail text-center">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <figure class="imghvr-hinge-down">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x211" alt="Bootstrap Thumbnail Customization">
                </figure>   
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5><b>Bootstrap Cards Design</b></h5>                            
                    <p class="card-description">Hi there How are you?</p>
                    <p><a href="#" id="thumbnail-btn" class="success-color btn btn-primary" role="button">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="column" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3-thumbnail text-center">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <figure class="imghvr-hinge-down">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x211" alt="Bootstrap Thumbnail Customization">
                </figure>   
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5><b>Bootstrap Cards Design</b></h5>                            
                    <p class="card-description">Hi there How are you?</p>
                    <p><a href="#" id="thumbnail-btn" class="success-color btn btn-primary" role="button">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="column" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3-thumbnail text-center">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <figure class="imghvr-hinge-down">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x211" alt="Bootstrap Thumbnail Customization">
                </figure>                        
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5><b>Bootstrap Cards Design</b></h5>                            
                    <p class="card-description">Hi there How are you?</p>
                    <p><a href="#" id="thumbnail-btn" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I even tried the `width:100%` for the thumbnail image** as

```
.thumbnail > img{width:100%; display:block;}
```

**The problem is, the `img` is not taking the full-width as that of its `column`**

Can anyone please help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the width to `100%` and the height to `auto`, this will expand it to full width.

**CSS:**

```
.thumbnail > figure > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Used `.img-fluid` for responsive image in Bootstrap.4. it have following css:

```
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/